# Differenze di uso tra "comparare" e "confrontare"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs, difference

Non capisco bene quale siano le differenze di uso tra i verbi "comparare" e "confrontare". Potreste spiegarmele? Ad esempio, cosa direbbe un professore a uno studente?:

- "Compara i risultati del tuo esercizio con quelli della tua compagna"

oppure

- "Confronta i risultati del tuo esercizio con quelli della tua compagna"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comparare%2Cconfrontare&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomparare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconfrontare%3B%2Cc0) comparare vs confrontare.

[Comparare](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/comparare.shtml):

> - [sogg-v-arg-prep.arg] Confrontare una cosa con un'altra SIN paragonare: c. il francese con l'italiano
> - [sogg-v-arg] Confrontare due cose tra loro: c. due lingue

Sono in sostanza due sinonimi. Comparare è un po' più formale e meno usato di confrontare (vedi Ngram) ma il significato è lo stesso. In particolare tra i loro sostantivi, *confronto* è di gran lunga più comune di *comparazione*.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comparazione%2C%20confronto&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomparazione%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconfronto%3B%2Cc0) comparazione vs confronto.

Un professore con uno studente potrebbe usare entrambi i termini, più probabilmente direbbe *confronta* nel contesto.

Comment: Aggiungo che c'è un'espressione idiomatica: "confrontarsi con un problema" (o con una persona),  significa doverlo affrontare, doverci aver a che fare (qui non si può usare "comparare").

Comment: Non sono sicura: è anche vero che confrontare regge la preposizione "con" e comparare la preposizione "a"?

Answer (score 6):

Sono sinonimi ma hanno accezioni di significato un po' diverse:

Comparare ha la radice latina di Paro, disporre. Quindi disporre insieme. Confrontare ha la radice latina di Frons, fronte. Quindi porre insieme di fronte.

Comparare ha un significato tendenzialmente neutro, mentre confrontare ha un significato tendenzialmente antagonistico.

Inoltre si compara qualcosa perchè ci si aspetta risultati simili. Si confronta qualcosa perchè ci si aspetta risultati diversi, soprattutto, se in uno dei due casi migliori.

Le forme:
"Confronta quello che ho fatto io con quello che hai fatto tu e ti renderai conto che ho lavorato il doppio" e "Ho comparato i dati e non c'erano discrepanze" suonerebbero più corrette delle forme con l'utilizzo dell'altro verbo.

Answer (score 1):

In effetti la differenza tra i due è sottile, ma c'è:

Confrontare è più usato quando si vogliono individuare delle differenze tra due oggetti, persone, cose, ect.
Ad esempio due avversari messi a confronto, mi aspetto che uno sia il vincitore o che abbia la meglio sull'altro.

Comparare è usato quando si vogliono individuare delle uguaglianze tra oggetti, persone, cose.
Esempio comparare delle zollette di zucchero, mi aspetto che abbiano lo stesso peso, la stessa forma.

Ritornando alle zollette di zucchero quindi potrei dire:
Ho comparato due zollette di zucchero, avevano peso e forma simile, ma confrontandole, il sapore di una era migliore dell'altra, la seconda doveva essere stantia (ovvero vecchia).

Comment: È un'opinione interessante, che non avevo mai incontrato. Posso chiederti da dove ti deriva? I dizionari non mi sembra che riportino questa distinzione: per esempio, alla voce confrontare del Treccani si menzionano esplicitamente «la somiglianza, le affinità, le differenze».

Comment: I dizionari li danno come sinonimi, ma comparare viene spesso usato per stabilire delle uguaglianze tra cose, presone, etc. Esempio: "È ceco come una talpa", vuol dire comparare la vista della persona suddetta a quella della talpa. In genere esprime un risultato basato su un analisi. Confrontare è l'atto di analizzare per trarre dei risultati.